# Correct line spacing when changing font size without causing the end of the paragraph

Tags: environments, fontsize, paragraphs, line-spacing, vertical-spacing

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]%
\begingroup%
\tiny\color{red}%
\lipsum[2]%
\endgroup%
\lipsum[3]%
\end{document}
```

Which produces the following output:

---

[image: problem]

---

The problem I have is that I would like the linespacing to be recomputed for the part of the text with a tiny size. A way to achieve that would be to add a `\par` in the group:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]%
\begingroup%
\tiny\color{red}%
\lipsum[2]%
\par%
\endgroup%
\lipsum[3]%
\end{document}
```

which now produces the following:

---

[image: par]

---

which is better, but I would like to stay in the same paragraph and avoid a linebreak.

---

**QUESTION:** How to obtain a tiny linespacing for the text written in a tiny font without causing the end of the paragraph and a linebreak? (I would like a solution that would be compatible with any font size).

Comment: you need a paragraph at the tex level as there can only be one baseline space per paragraph, but you can hide the linebreak but  the last half line of small text would need the large baselineskip which may look odd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can record the position of the end of the small text and then back up to start the large text at that position, takes two runs.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\makeatletter
\begingroup%
\tiny\color{red}%
aaa \lipsum[2]%
{\normalsize\strut}%
\pdfsavepos\write\@auxout{\gdef\string\wdA{\the\pdflastxpos}}
\par%
\endgroup
\nopagebreak\kern-\baselineskip
\noindent\pdfsavepos\write\@auxout{\gdef\string\wdB{\the\pdflastxpos}}
\ifx\wdA\undefined\else 
\kern\numexpr\wdA-\wdB\relax sp\fi
\lipsum[3]%
\end{document}
```

[image]